# Optimization of multple if condition in python

Tags: python

I have a python condition statement like this

```
if 'small_cover' not in request.POST or 'medium_cover' not in request.POST or 'large_cover' not in request.POST:
    # do somethinf here.
```

Can there be the shortest way than this.

Comment: What framework provides the `request.POST` object? Is this Django, for example?

Comment: `if not all(thing in request.POST for thing in ('small_cover', ...)):`?

Comment: yes it is the dictionary of POST objects

Comment: @wrufesh: no, it is an *object that acts like a dictionary*. It depends *heavily* on what type of object it really is what answers I can give you.

Comment: If it *is* just a dictionary, this question is a duplicate. But the best way to do this with a true dictionary may not be the best way to do it with, say, a Werkzeug MultiDict object.

Comment: I've now dupe-hammered this to the canonical multiple-keys-in-dictionary post, as the answers here did not add anything new to the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not all(x in request.POST for x in ('small_cover', 'medium_cover', 'large_cover')):
```

or even more concisely:

```
if not all(x+'_cover' in request.POST for x in ('small', 'medium', 'large')):
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `any` which will short circuit if we find [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) of the three items are not in  `request.POST`

```
if  any(x not in request.POST for x in ('small_cover',  'medium_cover','large_cover')):
```